# What is the best and worst case search performance for a balanced BST?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What is the best and worst case search performance for a balanced BST? how can I Explain in one sentence when each case occurs?

Comment: Can you explain in more than one sentence? That is, the difficulty is only with the wording of the explanation? Or with understanding of the algorithm as well?

Comment: For balanced BST i believe it should be O(logN) (both cases) where N is the number of elements in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Best case: when the searched element is at the root of the tree. You get O(1).

Worst case: when the searched element is at the leaf <strike>of the longest branch, the tree is one-sided. You get O(n).</strike> You get O(log n).

Comment: he is asking about the Balanced Binary Search Tree (the difference between the height of left subtree and right subtree is no more than 1). So the worst case is ``O(logn)``

Comment: Oh my bad. Didn't see the "balanced" there.

Comment: thanks so much for all of them, actually I wrote this answer but I am not sure this is why I ask here, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

A search is made along a path from the root to a leaf, which has length Log n in a balanced tree.

Best case: hit at the first node, O(1)*.

Worst case: hit at the last node, O(Log n).

---

This is true if the implementation performs a test for equality, allowing early termination. Otherwise the full path will be followed in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

For a balanced BST:

- Best Case  : O(1)  When the node you are searching is at root (so you
  only need one comparision to find it)
- Worst Case : O(logn) when the    node you are searching is a leaf
  node (i.e bottom of the tree)